# Python: Print largest even number from 3 inputs without using list and max()

Tags: python

The program first asks for 3 integers then computes for the largest even from the set. It will print None if there are no even numbers. We are not allowed to use built-in functions (like max()) and not allowed to import math libraries.

What code can I use so it does not print None when I input x = 11, y = 11, z = 8? The correct output should be 8.

```
def getMaximum(x,y,z):
    if x >= y and x >= z:
        return x
    elif y >= x and y >= z:
        return y
    else:
        return z

def getLargestEven(x,y,z):
    LargestVal = getMaximum(x,y,z)          
    if LargestVal%2 == 0:                   
        return LargestVal
    elif x%2 == 0 and (x > y or x > z): 
        return x
    elif y%2 == 0 and (y > x or y > z):
        return y
    elif z%2 == 0 and (z > x or z > y):
        return z
    else:
        return None

x = int(input("Enter x: "))
y = int(input("Enter y: "))
z = int(input("Enter z: "))

print("Largest Even:", getLargestEven(x,y,z))
```

Comment: Take a pen and paper and go through your code with these values for your variables, and you will see what happens. Learning to debug is one of the most precious skills you have to develop.

Comment: Because you check if `z` is even `and (z > x or z > y)` but since `z` is not greater than `x` or `y`, that's not true, so it returns `None`; note that that tells you why you're getting `None` as a result, but your logic is wrong for other reasons as well. Come up with a number of tests to see if your code is wrong - don't stop at confirming a few cases work as expected.

Comment: Because `z > x or z > y` is not true.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a simple loop structure to test for the maximum even number among three

```
def getLargestEven(x,y,z):
    max_num = -99999999999999
    for num in [x,y,z]:
        if num%2==0:
            if num>max_num:
                max_num = num

    return None if max_num ==-99999999999999 else max_num
```

Comment: This will fail for `-99999999999999 - 1, 1, 3`. Using such 'magic' values should be avoided.

Comment: this is a homework assignment, its not practical for a real world program but there are solutions that are only appropriate under certain conditions. The probability of someone inputting that number is quite literally 0